# Linked list, check for duplicate inside the list before adding

Tags: c++

I'm trying to check for duplicates before adding into the list, but I couldn't figure out what when wrong. Hope you guys can help me out. I generate a random string to print out Sign[k], for example, "donkey".

```
while (temp1 != NULL)
{
    if (strcmp (static_cast <char *>((temp1 -> data)), temp)== 0)
        return false;

    temp1 -> next = head;
    head = temp1;
}

return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function `testSimilar`, instead of:

```
temp1 -> next = head;
head = temp1;
```

You probably meant:

```
  temp1 = temp1 -> next;
```